# Semantic-UI Menu Styling Issue

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I want to style the menu by moving the text to the middle. When I inspect the element on Chrome, it works when I change the align-self property to equal initial or normal. How do I add this css in the code? this is what I have tried:

Menu code:

```
<Menu fluid={true} pointing secondary size="massive" color="grey" width="20%">

<Menu.Item 
          class=".ui.secondary.pointing.menu"
          position='left'
          name='home'
          // active={activeItem === 'home'} 
          onClick={handleItemClick}
          as={Link} 
          to='/createcampaign'
          className = {classes.text}
          
          
      >
        Start A Campaign
    </Menu.Item>
```

Styles.scss:

```
.ui.secondary.pointing.menu{
align-self: initial;
border-bottom: 0.4px solid #E1E1E1 !important;
box-shadow: none;
align-self: none;
}
```

Comment: can you provide a working example in codesandbox or some similar tool?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to do that

Comment: https://codesandbox.io it is free to create live examples

Answer (score 0):

check this example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-semantic-ui-forked-34y63?file=/src/index.js

I created this class to align its child elements:

```
.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

and added on `Menu` as `<Menu className='center' ...` it works! maybe there is a simple way but I did not find in the docs

Comment: I think I wrote it a little misleading. I meant centre in terms of the y-axis. So centre it on the vertical axis not horizontal

Comment: it seems to be in the middle for Y and X, if possible send an example with your problem.